# Knockout 3.0- Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have one page with multiple sections, which load one after the other (second section loads when section 1 is validated). I am using knockout 3.0 to perform validations in each section but I'm getting error-
Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Please help. Thanks!

HTML:
    
    
        
    
    
        
            
        
    
    
        
            
                close
            
                proceed

```
<section id="modal2resetpwd" class="modal fade hide component">
<header class="modal-header">
    <h1 class="modal-title form-title" id="modalTitle"></h1>
</header>
<article class="modal-body" id="modalContent">
    <p class="intro-line">enter the id you want to use for verification</p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="employeeid" name="identifier" checked="checked">employee id</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="buid" name="identifier">BU id</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div data-bind='validationOptions: { messageTemplate: "customMessageTemplate" }'>
        <input style="width: 50%; margin-left: 20%;" data-bind="value: identifierId, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { 'keyup': checkNumber }" />
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="email" name="identifier" disabled="disabled">email id</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="phone" name="identifier" disabled="disabled">phone number</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</article>
<footer class="modal-footer">
    <div class="modal-controls">
        <a class="btn btn-icon" href="javascript:ActivatePanel(1)">
            <img class="icon-image" src="~/Content/Images/icon-return.png" />return</a>
        <a class="btn btn-icon" data-bind="click: ValidateIdentifierId">
            <img class="icon-image" src="~/Content/Images/icon-run.png" />proceed</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

JS:
    var patterns = {
    email: /^([\d\w-.]+@([\d\w-]+.)+[\w]{2,4})?$/,
    phone: /^\d[\d -]*\d$/,
    identifier: /^\d*/,
    postcode: /^([a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9]?[a-zA-Z\s]?\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2,2})|(GIR 0AA)$/
    };

```
var viewModelEmail = {
emailAddress: ko.observable().extend({
    required: { message: requiredEmail },
    pattern: {
        params: patterns.email,
        message: invalidEmail
    }
}),

ValidateEmailAddress: function () {
    if (viewModelEmail.emailerrors().length == 0) {
        // TO DO Validate entered email address 
        ActivatePanel(2);
    } else {
        viewModelEmail.emailerrors.showAllMessages();
    }
}
};

viewModelEmail.emailerrors = ko.validation.group(viewModelEmail);

ko.applyBindings(viewModelEmail, $("#modal1resetpwd")[0]);

var viewModelId = {
identifierId: ko.observable().extend({
    required: { message: requiredIdentifierId },
    minLength: 2,
    maxLength: 6,
    pattern: {
        params: patterns.identifier,
        message: invalidId
    }
}),

ValidateIdentifierId: function () {
    if (viewModelId.iderrors().length == 0) {
        // TO DO Validate entered email address 
        ActivatePanel(3);
    } else {
        viewModelId.iderrors.showAllMessages();
    }
}
};

viewModelId.iderrors = ko.validation.group(viewModelId);

ko.applyBindings(viewModelId, $("#modal2resetpwd")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like it says, you're calling `ko.applyBindings` for `#modal2resetpwd` twice even though the bindings are different.  You can only apply bindings once.

You can wrap the two separate viewmodels in another object, the *actual* ViewModel:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    id: viewModelId,
    email: viewModelEmail,
}, document.getElementById("modal2resetpwd"));
```

Then you would have to update your HTML to use this.

```
data-bind="click: id.ValidateIdentifierId"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am calling ko.applyBindings twice, one for modal1resetpwd and then for modal2resetpwd. Should it not work?